# C : comparing string to "%.c"?

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, pointers

I am trying to do something tricky.
I would like to open a file, and check whether the file contains the substring: `echo %.c`.
Exactly this substring: `echo`, followed by a percent sign, followed by a dot, followed by character `c`.

I just need to find the correct syntax to use for `strstr`.

My code:

```
FILE *search = fopen(file, "r");
if (!search) {
    errx(2, "File not found.");
    exit(2);
}
char line[8193];
bool check = false;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), search)) {
    if (strstr(line, "echo %.c")) {
        ck = true;
    }
}
fclose(search);
```

This does not work because this is a reserved syntax for `printf`. How can I change it for it to work?

Comment: What do youmean by "reserved syntax for printf"? The printf format string syntax is irrelevant in `strstr()` - it just takes the string you give it, with no formatting/interpretation.

Comment: It will look for a string "echo %.c". There's no "reserved syntax for printf".

Comment: If this is "approximate code" (e.g. `ck`) and you obtained the search string from `fgets` too, it can contain a newline, so it will only match if it appears at the end of the line.

Comment: What is the exact error message and where does it come from? Also post the complete code.

Comment: you should post your exact code, the one you use to test.... and not a replica of it... as one of the answers says: you have some differences that make your program not executable, so you can eliminate some of the problems if what you post is not what you test.

Comment: you should visit [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how (and why) you should post the exact code you use instead of copying a snippet of it here.  There are serious reasons to think you have modified your code on posting, and you can eliminate part or the whole problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I checked that the percent sign works fine.
Check this example: https://onlinegdb.com/ByHR13MI8

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char *line = "The interest rate is 3%.";
    const char *percentage;
    printf("%s\n", line);
    percentage = strstr(line, "3%");
    if (percentage)
        printf("%s", percentage);
    else
        printf("not found");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A single example is not a formal proof, but indeed the `%` sign is perfectly fine the the posted code.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes, you are completely right. But a test code can be a first indication if a solution may work or not. (I am aware of that a working code is no guarantee that the code is universally valid.)

Answer (score 3):

`printf` has nothing to do with this. `"echo %.c"` is a perfectly fine string to pass to `strstr`. There must be something wrong with your environment that prevents you from running this program.

Note however that the program might fail to find the search string if it happens to be present in lines longer than 8192 bytes, overlapping the boundary of 8192 byte blocks. Quite unlikely, but possible on a perverse test bench.

Note also that `ck = true;` is a typo: the variable name is `check`. This makes me wonder what other differences are present in the actual offending code. Did you mean to search for `"echo *.c"`

Answer (score 1):

This is the prototype for `strstr`:

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

This usage looks just fine to me. I don't know what you're talking about by "reserved syntax for `printf`" unless it's some obscure incorrect compiler warning. The C standard mentions nothing of the sort.

If your code won't compile because of `ck = true;`, try changing it to use your variable name—`check = true;`.